# Why has the Intel Itanium failed to take on the world?

Tags: intel, microprocessor

Last summer, the Itanium has finally been discontinued, twenty years after its release. It was a promising technology, but in the end it turned out to not really be the case.

Beside a few niche markets in the enterprise world, it failed to conquer the desktop world and ultimately, to replace the x86 architecture which was designed way earlier.

**Question:**

Why were there high expectations for the Itanium but in the it failed to deliver in practice?

Comment: "High expectations"? More like a lot of marketing bull, widely recognized as such even at the time. People were calling it "Itanic" before the first generation of the chip was even available for preorder. It needed compiler tech that *still doesn't exist today*, and it launched directly into the power wall. It would've been discontinued long ago if any company but Intel had been behind it.

Comment: (If I were a conspiracy theorist, I would put forward the suggestion that Intel *deliberately* produced a chip it *knew* would be a legendary failure, because with enough marketing spin and enough patience, it could hype up the thing to the point where all its competitors in the high-end server space would bankrupt themselves chasing a mirage, leaving a vacuum for the x86 division to move into.  It worked on Digital, HP, and SGI, and it only didn't work on IBM because nothing can kill the Grimace.)

Comment: @zwol - I think you'd be wrong, because it was AMD, not Intel, that pushed x86 into 64-bit-ness, and Intel was forced to follow, thus sinking the Itanic.

Comment: Itanium? Bah! [iAPX 432](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_iAPX_432) or die trying!!!

Comment: @another-dave I said it was a conspiracy theory :-)  But remember that this was 20 years ago and, IIRC, it was still an open question back then whether the high-end server space _wanted_ to go 64-bit, particularly as 64-bit Windows (on Alpha) had been such a failure.  Some of the design features of Itanium make more sense if you imagine it as going after the _supercomputer_ market (then dominated by SGI) first.

Comment: @zwol - I think your definition of _supercomputer_ differs from mine, since I never considered SGI as a leader in supercomputers. Nice workstations, sure.

Comment: @JonCuster, whether they are supercomputer class or not can be debated but I think SGI computers like Power Challenge and Origin 3000 are way beyond workstations.

Comment: @zwol: Windows on Alpha *wasn't 64-bit* in any released version (Alphas were used at MS in developing 64-bit Windows for a while after it was dropped from released versions of Windows). The first released 64-bit Windows was on Itanium.

Comment: @JohnDallman I Did Not Know That™

Comment: @JonCuster I may be misremembering when this was, relative to when Itanium was the Next Big Thing, but SGI had a whole line of gigantic many-processor machines for number crunching ... I think it was called Origin? And they owned Cray for a while, too.

Comment: Octane, Onyx, or O2 (O2 was the lowest rung). Again, all workstation class. They were good for 3D work but did not compare to real supercomputers at the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR:

It wasn't a failure, it did deliver, it gained a foothold much like other non-x86 architectures at that time, and it faded like they all did.

---

> Why were there high expectations for the Itanium

Because the idea is great. Massively parallel execution without the need of complex rescheduling since the compiler had done all that work ahead of execution. After all, work that does not need to be done is done the quickest.

> but in the it failed to deliver in practice?

It didn't fail to deliver. It delivered as expected. The main issues were:

- Later delivery (but I'd say that's standard with every new design)
- Lag in compiler development
- Missing compatibility with existing (x86) software

While the first is rather standard with every new design, and the second was overcome in time; the real hurdle was the missing x86 compatibility. Intel targeted the Itanium at a high end market competing with large Unix or even mainframe systems, in an area where most software is custom made and only a small number of suppliers of standard components/software exist, which should be easy to convince to provide Itanium versions.

But they missed two important points:

**First**, the custom nature of software in that area would also mean that customers had to recompile all their own software in addition to changing the hardware. Software that may be decades old, written in other languages than C and most important with many project-specific extensions to these languages and their libraries.

There is a good reason that IBM /370ish machines are still ruling the ERP and financial world. Sure, the hardware is excellent and quite fitting the job and operating environments are quite capable, but it's their strict compatibility that is of most value here. Itanium-based machines would end up emulating a /370 to be useful - still not bad, but no gain either.

**Second**, Intel did not expect that PC (x86) software would grow into the server market the way that it did - as binary packages to be simply used.

At that point it's important to see not only that Intel lost the race against x86, but essentially all other CPU architectures did. From HP-RISC to SPARC (*1) they all went the same way as Itanium. They all gained some market share but have been superceded by x86 in the long run.

So, long story short: **Itanium did deliver and it faded like essentially all other non-x86 of that time** (*2).

---

> it failed to conquer the desktop world

That wasn't intended at all. At maximum, high-end workstations would be a target.

> it failed [...] to replace the x86 architecture

Again, not in general. Just in high end applications. Intel wanted to go after the server market by leapfrogging other more conventional ISAs. Of course, they wouldn't have argued against if Itanium had found its way within smaller machines in some distant future, but knowing Intel, it was never really considered.

---

*1 - Yes, I know that SPARC is quite alive, not at least due to Fujitsu still going strong - but it's a niche market compared to x86.

*2 - I know there is ARM, and it's going strong. Still, it's restricted to the phone and tablet market. ARM on desktop is, much like ARM in servers, always the next big thing - every year for the past 20 years. And no, Apple adopting ARM for desktop will not change this. They also did so, quite dedicated for PowerPC. Not to mention that Microsoft also tried for quite some time with ARM-based Windows. The issue here is essentially the inverse one of the Itanium, as x86 'owns' the middle field. No chance to score a winning goal. But that's another story.

Comment: You have made a number of assertions here that are plainly incorrect.  For example the ARM architecture is not at all restricted to the phone and tablet market.  Apple is now delivering Macs with ARM CPUs in them, many Chromebooks are ARM based.  AWS offers ARM/Graviton servers, containers, and now Lambdas at scale.  Also, SPARC is a dead architecture.  It was dead even before Oracle bought the remains of Sun.

Comment: I think the footnote covers Apple; also I was feeling contrary and had a quick look but of the 20 recommended Chromebooks for 2021 that I found, only one was ARM-based. Celerons and i3s seem to have ascended there.

Comment: ARM dominates the embedded space as far as I’m aware, but obviously that wasn’t a concern for Itanium. MIPS also lives on in embedded applications.

Comment: The "run existing software well" is hard, but Apple managed to do it.  Several times!  And therefore it is not an issue for their users.

Comment: One thing that talks for ARM getting a stronghold on the Mac platform is the power efficiency.   Same performance or better for half the power usage of the machine.  https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/328541-the-apple-m1-pro-and-m1-maxs-power-efficiency-should-rattle-intel-amd

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - Apple did it because _they controlled the toolchain_ as well as the _OS_ and could/would make the necessary (very large) investment to make everything work.  In the large system world there is no single toolchain vendor, nor is there a single OS vendor: users would have been on their own with support very spotty for quite a long time.  Digital did it too with the Alpha: first, by a totally excellent and innovative (as well as accurate) x86 emulation, and second, by somehow getting Microsoft onboard to provide the most popular x86 OS (as well as doing their own OS).

Comment: A major problem with the Itanium is that it's possible for multi-core processors to offer stronger or weaker semantic guarantees about when a core will do something versus when another core sees it happen, and processors that only provide weaker guarantees can run faster than those that offer stronger guarantees *when performing tasks for which the weaker guarantees are sufficient*, code designed around one set of guarantees will often be very hard to adapt to work efficiently and reliably on processors which don't support the same guarantees.

Comment: @davidbak They deliberately put themselves in a position to be able to do so.  Intel failed to provide a similar toolchain for Itanium.    And Microsoft of all should know that if they wanted to have success with an ARM based machine, it should be able to run x86 binaries even if slow.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - w.r.t. Apple - yes, they deliberately over many many years ensured that they'd have the only OS _and toolchain_ - Itanium from HP and/or Intel had no such advantage in the existing world.  If I'm understanding what you meant.  There were many _languages_ not to mention compilers.  They couldn't have provided them all.  Microsoft's position is the same as Apple's:  They don't give a darn about anything except _Windows_ executables - and they control Windows _and_ the most popular Windows toolchain (and have $$$).  They don't _need_ x86 binaries on ARM. For _Windows_.

Comment: I think the DEC Alpha had a somewhat similar problem.  Other processors would always guarantee that if programs running on two separate cores tried to write to adjacent bytes in memory, the actions would always behave as though performed as two independent writes whether or not the programmer indicated any need to accommodate that possibility.  On early versions of the Alpha, writing a byte required reading a 32-bit word, updating a byte within it, and writing back the whole word.  One could perform this operation in a way that would ensure that...

Comment: ...if two cores tried to update bytes within the same word, the conflict would be resolved in such a way as to leave the proper values in both bytes, but including such conflict resolution on *every action that tried to write a byte of memory* would grossly degrade performance, omitting it would make operation unreliable, and programming languages offered no means of identifying the tiny fraction of places it was actually needed.

Comment: But, you know, HP/Intel _could_ have provided very decent x86 emulation similar to the way Digital did with [FX!32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FX!32) - or, hey, even better!, because HP had damn good software engineering. But, they didn't.

Comment: BTW, Intel is doing this _now_ with Microsoft - their [Bridge technology](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/newsroom/news/intel-tech-unleashes-windows-experience.html) lets you run _Android_ apps on _Windows_.  If I understand correctly they do this via an Android byte-code-to-x64 layer (plus, of course, sufficient shims so that the Android framework can run on Windows).

Comment: This answers the wrong question. The question asks "Why has the Intel Itanium failed to take on the world?" The real answer is that it was never designed to. It was only ever really intended for servers. It also didn't deliver. By delivering we mean was a successful product that sold ereasonably well in its target market.

Comment: Furthermore, the assertions about ARM are true only in a very narrow sense. ARM64 is vastly more successful (as an architecture) than x86 and AMD64. Practically everybody who owns a mobile phone has a 64 bit ARM SoC.

Answer (score 10):

By the time it came to market, the market had changed with AMD introducing the 64-bit x64 architecture based on an extended x86 design.  This included 32-bit x86 mode which allowed the direct execution of existing 32-bit code as well as newer 64-bit code.

Intel delivered the first Itanium in 2001 which fell well short of expectations since it had severe performance limitations (coupled with high price) such that it made little sense to use it.  Intel updated the Itanium and introduced a better performing chip by 2002 but much of the damage had been done.

AMD introduced the x64 64-bit extended architecture in 2003 which offered better performance than even the updated Itanium for lower cost and essentially made the Itanium obsolete. By 2009 Intel had introduced their own Xeon server CPU which essentially copied the 64-bit extensions that AMD had developed which for all intents and purposes ended the viability of the Itanium architecture. It was basically all downhill from this point onward.

That coupled with the factors listed in Justme's answer doomed the Itanium from the start.

Comment: "Run existing software at full speed" turned out to be very important.

Comment: The ability of the Itanium to run x86 32-bit code was questionable at best.  Yes it could run it but the performance was terrible.

Comment: Intel adopted "Intel 64" much earlier than 2009; it appears the Nocona family supported it in 2004.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_NetBurst-based_Xeon_microprocessors#%22Nocona%22_(90_nm)

Answer (score 5):

When it was finally released, it was not intended for generic desktop market, it was targeted for enterprise servers and high performance computing systems.

It sounded promising, but it was delayed a lot, partly maybe because it was difficult to write compilers for the architecture, it cost a lot, did not perform well, and had limited software support so did not get enough base to be used a lot.

It was also not natively compatible with legacy 32-bit x86 code (OS and applications needed to be ported or run in emulation) and due to emulation x86 code ran 10 times faster on real x86 hardware than on Itanium.